# Visual FoxPro: MEMO Field contains all Strange characters. Is there a way I can recover the Original text of the MEMO field?

Tags: visual-foxpro

When I brows a Visual `FoxPro` Memo Field, the field contains strange characters such as :

> "Ñ²ÈÊ¼‡²·ÄÉ¿²º»¼¼†²º»¼Ê·¸ˆ†Ñ²¼ÅÄÊÊ¸ÂÑ²¼†²¼ÉÍ¿ÉÉv£©v©·ÄÉv©»È¿¼‘ÓÑ²¼‡²¼º»¹ÅÈ²¼¹¾·ÈÉ»Êˆv©ÏÃ¸ÅÂ‘ÓÑ²¼ˆ²¼ÉÍ¿ÉÉv—È¿·Â‘ÓÑ²¼‰²¼ÈÅÃ·Ävª¿Ã»Év¤»Ív¨ÅÃ·Ä‘ÓÓcÑ²¹ÅÂÅÈÊ¸Â²È»º†²½È»»Ä†²¸ÂË»†‘Óc²º»¼Â·Ä½‡†‰‰²Æ·Èº²ÆÂ·¿Ä²¼ˆ²¼ÉˆŠv±¦»¹¾ÅËÉvœ·Ã¿ÂÏ³c²Æ·ÈvÈ·Äº¼·Ê¾»Èv Å¾Äv¦»¹¾ÅËÉvº¿»ºvÅ¼v·vž»·ÈÊv—ÊÊ·¹ÁvÍ¾¿Â»vÍÅÈÁ¿Ä½v¹·ÈÈÏ¿Ä½vª¬vÉ»Ê„c²Æ·ÈvÓc`V"

This is in all the memo fields of the table. What causes this and how can I recover my data?

Comment: Are you looking in the .dbf or the .fpt?

Comment: i am looking in the fpt! Have tried looking at the code page! It appears to be correctly set to 1252! Have been trying to play around with STRCONV but not obtaining anything legible!

Comment: You cannot get the Memo field contents by looking at the FPT file.  You need to examine the contents of the specific Memo fields in the primary associated DBF table.  The best 'tool' to do that would be using Visual Foxpro - which would also give you the 'tools' to extract or otherwise use the fieldc contents.. But if you do not have that, you can find other DBF file 'viewers'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say 'recover'; do you know for certain that the MEMO fields previously contained plain text data that you could make sense of?  If it did and now it doesn't, it's possible you've been hit by encrypting ransomware malware.

If it's always been encrypted and you want to decrypt it outside whatever application created the files, you'll have to figure out what method was used to encrypt it and what key was used, or talk to the developer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that might cause this.

1. What kind of data is supposed to be in that memo field? It could be an image, video, an exe, a compressed file (zip, 7-zip, or other), or some other binary data. If that's the case, use COPY MEMO to write the data to a file, then examine the file.
2. Somehow the field might have gotten unicode into it. Your sample doesn't really look like unicode, but...
3. The data might be encrypted. If that's the case, you need to know the encryption scheme and the password.
4. The data might be corrupt, in which case you might be out of luck.

Comment: Are you familiar with FoxPro? The "Memo" field is a part of the user interface -- it's highly unlikely that the contents of a file would have ended up in the field unless someone put it there on purpose.

Comment: Indeed I am very familiar with FoxPro, having worked with it for more than twenty years. I have stored files of many types in memo fields. I would appreciate your not downvoting on a topic about which you clearly know nothing.